# Linux driver does not want to compile

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I have such a problem, I wrote the first driver (here is its code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void){
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello world\n");
  return 0;
}

static int hello_exit(void)
{
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye world");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

and compiled it via makefile (here is its code:

```
obj-m := hello.o
```

he issued:

```
$ make: *** No targets. Stop.
```

kernel version 5.9.8-2-MANJARO

I took an example from the book by Jonathan Corbert, Alesandro Rubin, Greg Kroah-hartman - 'linux device drivers'. it says that one line in the makefile is enough to compile this file

Comment: `obj-m := hello.o` should be `obj-m += hello.o`. And please show the rest of you makefile as there may be other errors.

Comment: If this the whole contents of your `Makefile`, then it doesn't contain any target but only a variable assignment. Either there is something missing in the `Makefile` or the file is intended to be included from some other `Makefile` which contains the missing targets and rules. If you followed some instructions for building a kernel module, please [edit] your question and add a link/reference to these instructions.

Comment: If that really is your whole makefile then suggest you go back to spend some time with your favourite search engine to do basic research. Any decent kernel module tutorial/guide will have a clear example of what a simple kernel module makefile should look like.

Comment: I suggest reading the docs: [Building External Modules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html).